# Spark ML: Taking square root of feature columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Hi I am using a custom UDF to take square root of each value in each column.

```
square_root_UDF = udf(lambda x: math.sqrt(x), DoubleType())

for x in features:
  dataTraining = dataTraining.withColumn(x, square_root_UDF(x))
```

Is there any faster way to get it done ? Polynomial expansion function is not suitable in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use UDF. Instead use built-in:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sqrt

for x in features:
    dataTraining = dataTraining.withColumn(x, sqrt(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

To add sqrt results as a column in scala you need to do the following:

```
import hc.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sqrt

val dataTraining = dataTraining.withColumn("x_std", sqrt('x_variance))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to speed-up your calculation in this case

1. put your data into a DataFrame (not RDD)
2. use vectorized operations (not lambda-operations with UDF) as suggested by @user7757642

this is an example if you dataTraining is an RDD then

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sqrt

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SessionName") \
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some_value") \
      .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(dataTraining)

for x in features:
    df = df.withColumn(x, sqrt(x))
```